# Ros2 and communication - How do you post a Ros2 message in a text box in Unity?

Tags: ros, communication, ros2, visualization

I am developing a project with [ros_msft_mrtk](https://github.com/ms-iot/ros_msft_mrtk) and would like to send simple messages via Ros2 to Unity or then to the Hololens2. Unfortunately, I don't understand Ros2's communication. I use the [SubscriptionExample](https://github.com/ms-iot/ros_msft_mrtk/blob/master/SampleProject/Assets/Scripts/Examples/SubscriptionExample.cs), added it to a GameObject and now want to display sented messages in a text field in Unity. That was my attempt:[image]

I get the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'std_msgs.msg.String' to 'string'`. How can I store a received std_msgs.msg.String in a string to output it in Unity and later on the HoloLens?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* luzylulilu.  Please don't post screenshots of code.  If possible, copy and paste the text.  Images aren't searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the tutorial that you linked.](https://github.com/ms-iot/ros_msft_mrtk/blob/11457b9e583ab2ce6ee0e3a0ddfc110b033ce575/SampleProject/Assets/Scripts/Examples/SubscriptionExample.cs#L28) The string value that you want is in the data field of the message `msg.Data` not the message named `std_msgs/String`

You can see the message definition [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/humble/std_msgs/msg/String.msg).